# When I run the C++ code, I always get Visual Studio error C2664

Tags: c++, c2664

When I use this code

```
if (GetKeyNameText(Key << 16, NameBuffer, 127))
{
    KeyName = NameBuffer;
    GoodKeyName = true;
}
```

I get the following error

> C2664 'int GetKeyNameTextW(LONG,LPWSTR,int)': cannot convert argument
>   2 from 'char [128]' to 'LPWSTR'

The `NameBuffer` says this:

> Error: argument of type "char*" is incompatible with parameter of type
>   "LPWSTR"

Any tips?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230355.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: where have you defined NameBuffer?

Answer (score 2):

You have `UNICODE` defined, which means all your functions and `TCHAR` and `LPTSTR` are defaulting to *wide* characters (`wchar_t`).

That means you can't use a narrow-character string (using `char`) without special care.

There is an easy solution, and that's to explicitly call the narrow-character version of the function: `GetKeyNameTextA`.

Another solution is to stop using `char` and change to `TCHAR` and related types, and use the `T` macro for string literals.

You might want to read more about [UNICODE in the Windows API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: um, a `LPWSTR` is always a `wchar_t*`

Comment: @NathanOliver The `UNICODE` macro causes `GetKeyNameText` to be an alias (a macro really) for `GetKeyNameTextW` which explicitly uses `LPWSTR`. If you see [the `GetKeyNameText` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646300%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it uses `LPTSTR` which is defined as `LPWSTR` if `UNICODE` is defined (and the narrow char `LPSTR` otherwise).

Comment: Oh.  I didn't see the function actually used an `LPTSTR`.  I just saw the `LPWSTR` from the Q.  btw I am not the down voter.

Comment: @NathanOliver Easy mistake. :) Oh and I try not to worry (to much!) about down-votes. If someone thinks my answer is bad it's their right to vote it like that. :)